# Problem with free memberships on contribution page (Resolved)

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, price-sets, configuration

I am working in CiviCRM 4.7.24/Drupal 7.56.

I have a contribution page for member signups. The page is using a price set that we just added a new free member type to. The rest of the member types are not free. The page works fine with the paid member types.

If someone selects the free membership they are forwarded to the billing info page but nothing is showing but the "Back" and "Confirm Contribution" buttons. If "Confirm Contribution" is clicked we get the error "Please review and correct errors before continuing" but there is nothing to review or correct.

Is it possible this is because we have "Execute real-time monetary transactions" selected in the page configuration?  Can there be free and paid options together on the same page?

Any suggestions on getting the free membership options to work?

Thanks!

EDIT Nov. 30: I've confirmed the issue is not specific to the free membership but anything free. If the final total is anything other than $0.00 it processes fine (even negative numbers)

Comment: Have you created a custom copy of the confirmation page template? If so, something could have been changed or be missing that is causing this.

Comment: Thanks, Jenni. I don't think it is a custom copy but I didn't develop the site so I'll have to double check.

Comment: I've come to a few sites where it was already done and they had templates that had removed quite a bit that caused problems down the line. When that happens, I duplicate my site so I have a dev version and delete all the custom templates. Then I can compare the live and dev versions to see if there was anything that I need to recreate to make them look the same (like sometimes sections may be rearranged in a different order).

Comment: Thanks. I needed a second set of eyes but we sorted out that there was some customization on the form (I inherited the site). We had to add a test  for a value of zero on the form and include a conditional response for that . All is good now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As posted under Jenni's comment. This problem was due to some customization in the contribution form. Once we put in a test for a zero balance and a conditional response everything is working again.

Comment: So glad to hear that you were able to find the issue. :)